# Regex alternatives not cached in group

Tags: regex

How to catch alternative into the nested group?

I want to return first capturing group of: `(.*)((core\/)?\/misc\/drupal\.js)` (i.e. anything before the string `core/misc/drupal.js` which may or might not contain `core/`).

However, the `core/` part always gets included to the first capturing group and not the second as supposed.

See also [this](https://regex101.com/r/cM5eY6/2) for an example.

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? Different regex engines perform differently.

Comment: I use the online tool for testing and intend to use `sed`in the bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your regex : you have one slash character at the end of the `(core\/)?` group, followed by another slash character in `\/misc\/drupal\.js`. This causes the `core/` part to be parsed in the first dot rule no matter what.

Removing the additional slash is not enough though. To avoid the dot eating up as many characters as possible, you have to disable the default **greedy** behaviour by adding a `?` to the `*` quantifier, like so :

```
(.*?)((core\/)?misc\/drupal\.js)
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/cM5eY6/3).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about greediness of the Kleene star. Dies the same go for +?

Comment: @smihael absolutely. It also works for `?`.